# .Q.hp giving error when used in try-catch

Tags: kdb

When tried to run .Q.hp (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#hp-http-post) in try-catch, I am getting an error ".[k){hmb[x;`POST;(y;z)]};[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c8be683;[Ljava.lang.Object;@724c1762;]"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it, any help would be appreciated

```
//defaine args
args:`channel`fallback`pretext`color`title`messageValue!("qatesting";"qatesting";"";"";(string .proc.hostip)," This is a test run, plz ignore";"");

//works fine
.Q.hp[webhookKey;"application/json";(.j.j raze (enlist (`channel`link_names`attachments)!(args[`channel];1b;((enlist (`fallback`pretext`color`fields)!(args[`fallback];args[`pretext];args[`color];((enlist (`title`value`short)!(args[`title];args[`messageValue];0b)))))))))]

//getting error
.[.Q.hp;(webhookKey;"application/json";(.j.j raze (enlist (`channel`link_names`attachments)!(args[`channel];1b;((enlist (`fallback`pretext`color`fields)!(args[`fallback];args[`pretext];args[`color];((enlist (`title`value`short)!(args[`title];args[`messageValue];0b))))))))));.lg.e[`slack_post_msg;"We have got an error when doing .Q.hp in .slack.post_msg"];]
".[k){hmb[x;`POST;(y;z)]};[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c8be683;[Ljava.lang.Object;@724c1762;]"
```

Comment: You have an extra semi colon on the end which is creating a projection. The .lg.e logger should also be wrapped in a one argument function which accepts the error message otherwise it will always run even when there is no error.

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#trap

Comment: ah I see now, thanks Matt for your quick response.

Comment: A slight side note, but you're also massively overusing parentheses and brackets which is making your code very hard to follow (thus leading to mistakes like this). Your original .Q.hp command can be simplified to: ```.Q.hp[webhookKey;"application/json";.j.j raze enlist`channel`link_names`attachments!(args`channel;1b;enlist`fallback`pretext`color`fields!(args`fallback;args`pretext;args`color;enlist`title`value`short!(args`title;args`messageValue;0b)))]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt's comment are correct. The main issues are the extra `;` in your `.[;;]` trap and the lack of a wrapper for the error handler to delay it's execution.

Breaking out the code more and using named variables can help you spot syntax errors more easily:

```
//A nice way to define dictionaries in a readable format
args:(!). flip (
 (`channel     ;"qatesting");
 (`fallback    ;"qatesting");
 (`pretext     ;"");
 (`color       ;"");
 (`title       ;"233312 This is a test run, plz ignore");
 (`messageValue;"")
 );

formatargs:(webhookKey;
      "application/json";
      (.j.j raze (enlist (`channel`link_names`attachments)!(args[`channel];
       1b;
       ((enlist (`fallback`pretext`color`fields)!(
          args[`fallback];
          args[`pretext];
          args[`color];
          ((enlist (`title`value`short)! 
             (args[`title];args[`messageValue];0b))))))))))

errHandler:{[err]
 .lg.e[`slack_post_msg;
       "We have got an error when doing .Q.hp in .slack.post_msg: ",err]
 }

.[.Q.hp;formatargs;errHandler]
```

I made the addition of `: ",err` so that the specific error thrown can be included in the error log which will help with debugging.

Comment: that's really helpful Rianoc, thanks for the giving the code snippets it helps to understand really well. Thank you very much again!